# Qualcomm Atheros Device can't find channel 13 WiFi (Ubuntu 16.04.2)

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

So I have the specific WLAN adapter as mentioned above (168c:0042 rev 31) but I can't find my WiFi in the list of WiFi networks if the channel is set to 13 (If I set it to < 13, I can find it but there so many WiFi networks on the other channels and they just mess up with mine and download speed gets really slow). I have set my region to my corresponding region using `sudo iw reg set` (I am fairly sure channel 13 is supported) but the problem persists. I was wondering if the source of the problem are any drivers (currently using ath10k).

EDIT 1:
Output of `iw list | grep Freq -A14`:

```
Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
--
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
              DFS state: usable (for 103 sec)
              DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
              DFS state: usable (for 103 sec)
              DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
              DFS state: usable (for 103 sec)
              DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
```

EDIT 2:
Output of `iw reg get`:

```
country GR: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

EDIT 3:
Output of `dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[    1.960190] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.252806] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.252815] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.269809] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6
[    2.269811] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.270128] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[    2.338522] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
[    4.117342] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.123902] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    4.123903] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.123905] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.123905] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[    4.128498] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Drivers are not a problem. They respect the hardware setting. You can compile `ath` that will allow you to switch regions. There is an option there. But you will need to compile a kernel, or at least a module.

Comment: Please post the output of `iw list | grep Freq -A14` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: And what does `iw reg get` show? It is wierd that the 12th channel is allowed.

Comment: That is what made me look into this.

Comment: It looks like a kernel bug for me. There is no reason that 12 is allowed and 13 is not.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Report it as a bug to Launchpad. Also you can search the net to look if this issue is addressed already.

Comment: But really I do not think it is important though. Do you know that either way there are only 3 channels that are 1, 6 and 13? It does not make much sense to use the 13.

Comment: I suggest that you try setting CRDA to a locale that supports channel 13, GB for example.

Comment: @chili555 already did that, thanks both of you and especially you Pilot6.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `dmesg | grep ath`  I think Pilot6's idea will work as I did the same late last year to fix an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable source code repositories in Software Sources and make sure build-essential is installed along with kernel header files.  You will also need Secure Boot disabled in BIOS

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Then we can download the kernel source code

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Then we can navigate to the ath folder

```
cd linux-hwe-4.8.0/drivers/net/wireless/ath
```

Open the file we need to change with gedit

```
gedit regd.c
```

Got to lines 235-237 and change

```
   case 0x66:
   case 0x69:
      return &ath_world_regdom_66_69;
```

To

```
   case 0x66:
      return &ath_world_regdom_66_69;
   case 0x69:
      return &ath_world_regdom_60_61_62;
```

Make sure the indentation matches, case should be one <kbd>TAB</kbd> from left and return should be 2 <kbd>TAB</kbd> from left then save the file and exit gedit.  Then we can compile the module with

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

It should compile if the changes were made correctly.  Then we can make a copy of the original module

```
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko.bak
```

Then we can copy the new module to the kernel

```
sudo cp ath.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
```

Reboot

This will need to be redone after a kernel update and you will need to

```
cd linux-hwe-4.8.0/drivers/net/wireless/ath
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko.bak
sudo cp ath.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
```

And reboot to have channel 13 in the new kernel

Reference: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=236357