# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 can't find channel 13 WiFi (Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS)

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless

I want to enable WiFi channels 13 on UbuntuServer18.04.2LTS. I tried to change regulatory domain by running `iw reg set JP` (I am in Japan).
Regulatory domain changed but Ubuntu could not find channel 13 WiFi.

```
iw list | grep Freq -A 14
    Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
```

Ubuntu's statuses are as follows

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-66-generic
```

---

```
$ lspci | grep Qualcom
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

---

```
$ iw reg get
global
country JP: DFS-JP
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM
    (4910 - 4990 @ 40), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
    (5030 - 5090 @ 40), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (59000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 10), (N/A)
phy#0
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

---

```
$ dmesg | grep ath
[    7.167872] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.168888] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    7.479266] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:04:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.479292] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:04:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.487836] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 168c:3363
[    7.487838] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    7.488472] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    7.564222] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ed3569e
[    8.168203] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    8.171207] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    8.171838] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    8.257109] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x0
[    8.257113] ath: EEPROM indicates default country code should be used
[    8.257113] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    8.257115] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[    8.257116] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[    8.257116] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[    8.269422] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Are you actually in Japan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qualcomm Atheros Device can't find channel 13 WiFi (Ubuntu 16.04.2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894283/qualcomm-atheros-device-cant-find-channel-13-wifi-ubuntu-16-04-2)

Comment: Not really a duplicate as things have changed since that answer was posted

Comment: It is a duplicate until OP compiles patch and states it doesn't work

Comment: Yes,I'm in Japan.

Comment: I already tried I Qualcomm Atheros Device can't find channel 13 WiFi (Ubuntu 16.04.2)
regd.c is not exitst