# Errors in make defconfig-ath10k .. Slow wifi with qualcomm Atheros QCA9377

Tags: wireless, make

The wifi signal is so weak in my laptop with ubuntu boot but works just fine with windows boot:
I have tried all the possible ideas and seen a lots of forums but the wifi is still slow. I only get speed of 1 to 3 mbps with ubuntu boot but with windows boot i get roughly 30 mbps of speed.
In one forum i have found of backports for a qualcomm modem but every time i try to compile it i get errors.

**If anyone can help me with the backports it would be great:**

**My current kernel is:5.8.0-41-generic**

**When i run "lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280" this command i get:**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

**When i run 'make defconfig-ath10k' i get errors like:**

```
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5553’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5555’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5557’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5559’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5561’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5563’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5566’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5568’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5570’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5572’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5574’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5576’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5578’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5580’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5582’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5584’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5586’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5588’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5590’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5592’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5594’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5596’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5598’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5600’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5602’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5604’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5606’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5608’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5610’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5612’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5615’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5617’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5619’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5621’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5623’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5625’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5627’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5629’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5631’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5633’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5635’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5637’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5639’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5641’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5643’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_5645’: Permission denied
 done.
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
lex -ozconf.lex.c -L zconf.l
yacc -ozconf.tab.c -t -l zconf.y
yacc: e - line 97 of "zconf.y", syntax error
%destructor {
^
make[2]: *** [Makefile:20: zconf.tab.c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile.real:41: defconfig-ath10k] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:43: defconfig-ath10k] Error 2
```

**When i run this command with sudo also i get errors similar like this.**

**If someone can help me with this would be a very great help. I am about to go mad with this slow wifi..**

Comment: For context, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/702443/134205)

Comment: In stalling a 6 year old driver is unlikely to help, even if you could compile it. Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo dmesg | grep ath` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Show only your router and omit the MAC address like this: `GBR5   Infra  149   405 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2`

Comment: Have you checked ufw to make sure no rules were set by rogue applications. It is a long shot but a possibility. It happened to me once and I put up with it for a long while before finding it by accident. It is worth checking.

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing any of the first 5 options I listed?
Please post feedack.

Answer (score 1):

[Official info](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/qca9377):
"The QCA9377 is a single-die wireless local area network (WLAN) and Bluetooth combination solution to support 1 × 1 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN standards and Bluetooth 5.0 + HS, designed to deliver superior integration of WLAN/Bluetooth and low-energy technology."

One possible cause for slow wifi is interference between bluetooth and wifi.
Before trying an old driver, try configuring your system with a current driver.
This is a list of actions by increasing difficulty:

1. **Disabling bluetooth**. You can do this via CLI with `systemctl stop bluetooth`, via GUI with *Settings* -> *Bluetooth* -> Move the slider at the top right, or perhaps via BIOS configuration.
2. **Getting closer** to the router (at least to try).
3. **Changing firmware**.
   [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1312339/226614) reports that "removing the `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin` file and rebooting helped. The system works with the previous `firmware-5.bin`."
4. **Changing WiFi band**. Select a different SSID, or select the band via `nm-connection-editor`. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231022/how-can-i-get-the-band-2-4-5-ghz-selection-back-in-wifi-settings-ubuntu-20) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419039/prefer-5ghz-to-2-4ghz-band-for-specific-wifi-network-ssid-without-using-bssid). See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235445/226614) to show the relevance, even if possibly not your case.
5. **Updating to kernel 5.11**.
6. **Changing WiFi channel**. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/895331/226614) and [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=236357&start=20); requires recompiling the driver.
7. **Changing WiFi antenna**. For some adapters, it is possible to select the antenna to use. I am not sure yours has more than one antenna. You could check with `modinfo ath10k_pci`, it will show all `parm`s that can be selected.

Please post the output of the following commands:

```
$ modinfo ath10k_pci
$ iw dev
$ ifconfig -a
$ inxi -F
$ dmesg | grep ath
```

As per [this recent post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1277359/226614), there are not so many options for the driver: `irq_mode`, `reset_mode`.
Perhaps now there are a few more.

If alternatives above don't work, you could try

1. Using a backport, as you tried. To solve this part, please post more info. In which directory you are compiling? What are the permissions? See [this old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/607982/226614).

**Sources**:

1. [ath10k installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation)
2. [My Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless adopter is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Vendor: Lenovo Model:E41-25)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277359/my-qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-adopter-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)
3. https://forum.openwrt.org/t/ath10k-pci-firmware-lacks-feature-flag-indicating-a-retry-limit-of-2-is-ok-requested-limit-4/79694
4. [More wifi issues - Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 ath10k_pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878097/more-wifi-issues-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-ath10k-pci)
5. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-ar/000144425/killer-wireless-firmware-update-guide-for-ubuntu-systems
6. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2389285&page=2

Comment: To make "3. Changing firmware." survive updates, do `mkdir /usr/local/share/my-dpkg-divert; dpkg-divert --divert /usr/local/share/my-dpkg-divert/firmware-6.bin.distrib --rename /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin`. Undo with `dpkg-divert --rename --remove  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin`

Comment: Any updates on this? Even with this advice, I'm not beating 6 MB/s.